# When to attach debugger to w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. My client is a Windows forms. I have provided service reference in my client application, so that it can generate server proxies (based on the service wsdl) and access methods exposed in my service. If I want to debug the server code,  I can step into(F11) that server method from my client application. I understand that I am not actually debugging the server code, but I am stepping into the proxy  generated by the client. I am confused that for some services, for debugging the server side code, it is often suggest to attach the debugger of client application to w3wp.exe. Why is this done, is there any reason for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this before. I think that Visual Studio is smart enough to detect that the server code is hosted inside IIS, and it suggests that you attach to the application pool inside IIS, if you do this you can actually debug the WCF service code.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly suggested to ensure you are testing the latest service code.
if you are debugging the proxy, you have to make sure you update the proxy for every change made in it or you will still be looking at the old proxy while the actual service has changed and the reference is not updated.
if you attach a debugger to w3wp.exe, you will be hitting the current version of the WCF service code and not the version in your proxy.